# Unity Random Range doesn't work as expected

Tags: unity-game-engine, random

I programmed a little pong clone.
At the start, the ball spawns in the middle of the field.

**Expected output:**
I want the ball to fly in 45 degree angles to the upper right and left, and lower right and left randomly.

**Real output:**
The ball only flies to the upper right and lower left.

**Code:**

```
public class BallController : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed;
private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
private int counter;

void Start() {
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    SetStartPosition();
}


public void SetStartPosition() {
    this.transform.position = new Vector3 (395f, 295f, 0f);
    int xVector = GetRandom ();
    int yVector = GetRandom ();
    float x = (float) xVector;
    float y = (float) yVector;
    Vector2 movement = new Vector2 (x, y);
    rb2d.velocity = movement * speed;
}

private int GetRandom() {
    int i = 0;
    do {
        Random.InitState((int) System.DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        i = Random.Range (-1, 2);
    } while (i == 0);
    return i;
}

}
```

Comment: Are you sure? I tried the code and i got all posible values. You can do an easy test with for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){print(GetRandom() + " " +GetRandom());} in Start. And you don't need Random.InitState((int) System.DateTime.Now.Ticks) that is used to set the seed and you usally only set it once if you want the same result everytime.

Comment: Wait I found the problem. It was Random.InitState((int) System.DateTime.Now.Ticks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random.InitState is meant to be used to seed the random engine. Random numbers from the Random class are not random as such, they are [pseudo-random.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) Pseudo-random numbers are deterministic; if you call Random.InitState with the same seed and then call Random.Range with the same arguments, you'll always get the same value. Since you're calling GetRandom twice so close to each other, you're probably reseeding the engine to the same value (or close to it) so then you get a random number that's the same as the last one. You should seed your engine only once. [This is covered in the Unity documentation.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.InitState.html) In fact, according to the documentation:

> The seed is normally set from some arbitrary value like the system clock before the random number functions are used. This prevents the same run of values from occurring each time a game is played and thus avoids predictable gameplay. However, it is sometimes useful to produce the same run of pseudo-random values on demand by setting the seed yourself.

So unless you have a good reason to seed the engine yourself, you should leave it up to the engine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `Random.InitState((int) System.DateTime.Now.Ticks)` `InitState` is used to set the seed and usually only once to get the same result everytime. It seems that by setting the seed every time it makes it return the same values (or the same 2 outputs).